# Get lowest value in a column for each spreadsheet in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an 'information' spreadsheet to gather informations from all the spreadsheets located within a specific folder.

I have this code that allows me to get the spreadsheet name and ID (Name in column 1 and ID in column 2)

```
function list_all_files_inside_a_folder(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('myfolderID');
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','ID']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getId());
    list.push(row);
  }
   sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

But I would like to also get a 3rd information : each spreadsheet in the folder has a column filled with numbers. I would like to fetch the lowest number of this column and put it a the 3rd column of my 'information' spreadsheet.
Any advice on how to do that ?

Edited code

```
function list_all_files_inside_a_folder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('MyfolderId');
  var list = [['Name', 'ID', 'lowest number']];
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Google Pixel 2");
    var value = Math.min(...sheet.getRange("C1:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, [c]) => {
      var t = c.match(/[\d-.]+/);
      if (c.toString() && t && !isNaN(t[0])) ar.push(Number(t[0]));
      return ar;
    }, []));
    list.push([file.getName(), file.getId(), value]);
  }
  sh.getRange(1, 1, list.length, list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve all Spreadsheet files from the specific folder.
- You want to retrieve the Spreadsheet title, Spreadsheet ID, and the lowest value from the column "C".
- You want to put the retrieved values on the active sheet.

From your question, unfortunately, I couldn't confirm that the information about the sheet that you want to retrieve the lowest value. So, in this modification, I proposed 2 patterns.

#### Modified script:

```js
function list_all_files_inside_a_folder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###'); // Please set your folder ID.
  var list = [['Name', 'ID', 'lowest number']];
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets()[0];
    var value = null;
    try {
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      if (lastRow > 0) {
        var values = sheet.getRange("C1:C" + lastRow).getDisplayValues();
        var arr = values.reduce((ar, [c]) => {
          var t = c.match(/[\d-.]+/);
          if (c.toString() && t && !isNaN(t[0])) ar.push(Number(t[0]));
          return ar;
        }, []);
        if (arr.length > 0) value = Math.min(...arr);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
      console.log(file.getId());
    }
    list.push([file.getName(), file.getId(), value]);
  }
  sh.getRange(1, 1, list.length, list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

- In this modification, by `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets()[0];`, the values of column "C" are retrieved from the 1st sheet of Spreadsheet. If you want to use the specific sheet, please modify it to `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("###sheetName###");`. By this, you can retrieve the values from the specific sheet using the sheet name.
- When this script is run, the Spreadsheet files are retrieved from the specific folder. And, the Spreadsheet title, Spreadsheet ID, and the lowest value from the column "C" are retrieved from each Spreadsheet. And, the retrieved values are put on the active sheet.
- From your provided sample Spreadsheets, it seems that in your Spreadsheets, the values of column "C" are variable types like the number, string and date object. For this, I calculated the lowest value from the display value.
- When I tested your all Spreadsheets, it seems that the values of column "C" have the text document. In this case, another error occurs. For this, I also modified the script.

  - So, in this case, when the values of column "C" has no numbers, the column "C" has no the lowest value. Please be careful about this.
- And, in this modification, if an error occurs for retrieving the lowest value, the error message and the spreadsheet ID are showin in the log.

#### References:

- [open(file)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile)
- [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)